# Rails 3 - Display hash from controller to view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a hash in my application controller

```
def search
    render layout: "application", template: "search"
       @result = { keyOne: "testing the hash", keyTwo: "this is value two" } 
end
```

app/views/search.html.erb

```
<!-- display hash reults -->
<p>
    <%= @result[:keyOne] %>
</p>
```

I'm getting the error: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass. I've tried @result.keyOne, and several other variances but still nothing.

Please, please help!

Comment: The problem is not w/ your hash access, it looks like `@result` is nil.

Comment: You have to make sure that you call `@result` in the view corresponding to your controller's action. It seems to not be the case here. (if this search method is in the SearchesController, the view should be located here: `app/views/searches/search.html.erb`)

Comment: You can have that function called for all of that controller's actions by `before_action :search`, or, if you put the function and that line in the application controller, for all controller actions in your app.

Comment: @Alex.Bullard how is result nil if I have it initialized in the application controller?

Comment: @MrYoshiji that's not the problem. The view is in app/views/search.html.erb, I've also tried adding the hash to the index action in the application controller and adding the erb to the index view.

Comment: I don't see you initializing `@result`. You are initializing `@testing`. Also you need to initialize your variable before rendering the template

Comment: @blnr well if your view is actually located @`app/views/search.html.erb`, then yes, it is the problem. The structure of the views folder in Rails is `app/views/:controller_name/:action_name.html.erb`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Initialize the variables you want to use in the template before rendering the template
2. Make sure that you use the correct variable name.(you are initializing `@testing`, but using `@result` in your template)

> ```
> def search
>     @result = { keyOne: "testing the hash", keyTwo: "this is value two" } 
>     render layout: "application", template: "search" 
> end
> ```

Comment: Oh my God, thank you. This was driving me crazy. The issue was that I needed to initialize the variable before rendering.